# Disable datepicker selection in jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a need to disable the date selection. User can view the default date loaded from back end, but he/she show not change the date.

I have made the field readonly but still it is allowing me to change the date.

Code:

```
      $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").attr('readonly',true).datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'


        }); 



     <div class="testimonials">
            <div class="left">
                <label>Deposit Date</label>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input name="depositDate" value="${depositDetails.DPST_DTE}"
                    id="datepicker" readonly/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: use destroy method to remove datepicker from the element

Comment: don't enable the datepicker in the first place??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you achieve what you want.

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").attr('readonly',true).datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
  }
  $('#datepicker').datepicker("hide");
});
```

you can the below snippet to disable other dates.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
  minDate: 'dateFromBackend',
  maxDate: 'dateFromBackend',
});
```

working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gt7pjq9r/)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. When ever user tries to click on the Deposit date, date picker show the date and other dates should be in disable mode. No selection should be allowed to change the date

Comment: @bharathi if you don't want any change to be allowed then this seems like a valid solution. It makes the field read-only and hides the datepicker. What's the point of showing the datepicker if the user can't do anything with it? Personally I would just not enable the datepicker in the first place, but this solution would also work.

Comment: I agree with ADyson.

Comment: Yes even I agree adyson. But as per customer requirement we have to show the date with all dates disabled, with only date that comes from back end enabled. Any way we can do this

Comment: You mean to say pop up should be visible and user should be able to select dates but date in the text field should not change once the user selects date?

Comment: yes, user can select  only the date which been loaded from back end not the other dates, fro example in the above image I attached user can select 1986-12-31, other dates should be in disable mode